# Weblogic & Tomcat simple java loop performance varies

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, weblogic

Have an issue where the performance of a simple loop (see code below in LoopTest.performTest) varies dramatically, but is consistent for the lifetime of the process.

For example, when run from within Weblogic/Tomcat it may achieve an average of 3.5 billion iterations per second. Re-start and it may only achieve 20 million iterations per second. This will remain consistent for the lifetime of the process. When it has been run directly from the command line, on every occasion, it has run fast.

This has been run under linux, windows, Tomcat & WebLogic. The slow execution occurs more regularly in WebLogic than Tomcat.

**Test Specifics**

The test code moves any potential OS calls (timing) to before and after the test, with differing size loops which should allow any slow OS calls to be apparent as a progressive apparent performance improvement as loop size increases.

The number of iterations performed by the test is determined by time (see runTest) rather than being fixed due to large variation in performance and is thus more complex than may initially be expected.

```
public static abstract class PerformanceTest {

    private final String name;

    public PerformanceTest(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Return value to ensure loops etc not optimised away.
     * 
     * @param loopCount
     * @return
     */
    public abstract long performTest(final long loopCount);

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

private static class LoopTest extends PerformanceTest {
    LoopTest() {
        super("Loop");
    }

    @Override
    public long performTest(final long loopCount) {
        long sum=0;
        for(long i=0;i<loopCount;i++) {
            sum+=i;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}

public static List<PerformanceTest> loadTests() {

    List<PerformanceTest> performanceTests = new ArrayList<PerformanceTest>();

    performanceTests.add(new LoopTest());

    return performanceTests;
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    int maxDuration = 30;

    if (argv.length == 1) {
        maxDuration = Integer.parseInt(argv[0]);
    }

    List<PerformanceTest> tests = loadTests();

    for(PerformanceTest test : tests) {
        runTest(test, maxDuration);
    }
}

public static void runTest(PerformanceTest test, int maxDuration) {
    System.out.println("Processing " + test.getName());

    long stopDuration = 1000 * maxDuration;

    long estimatedDuration = 1;
    long priorDelta = 1;
    long loopCount=10;

    while (estimatedDuration < stopDuration) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        test.performTest(loopCount);

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long delta = endTime - startTime;

        estimatedDuration = delta * Math.max(10, delta / Math.min(estimatedDuration, priorDelta));

        if (estimatedDuration <= 0) {
            estimatedDuration = 1;
        }

        priorDelta = delta;

        if (priorDelta <= 0) {
            priorDelta = 1;
        }

        if (delta > 0) {
            double itemsPerSecond = 1000 * (double)loopCount / (double)delta;

            DecimalFormat formatter;
            if (itemsPerSecond < 1) {
                formatter = new DecimalFormat( "#,###,###,##0.000");
            } else if (itemsPerSecond < 10) {
                formatter = new DecimalFormat( "#,###,###,##0.0");
            } else { 
                formatter = new DecimalFormat( "#,###,###,##0");
            }

            System.out.println("    " + loopCount + " : Duration " + delta + ", Items Per-Second: " + formatter.format(itemsPerSecond));
        }

        loopCount*=10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running weblogic with the same JDK as Tomcat? What do you think the result of your microbenchmark means?

Comment: Using the same JDK for all tests. As for what it means - I don't know, I guess if I did I wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: Are you certain Weblogic isn't running with [JRockit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/overview/index.html)? Because, it historically does.

Comment: Have specifically checked for the jdk being used. But even if it was JRocket on weblogic, the nature of the issue still remains, and it also occurs under Tomcat but just not as often.